How to customize the positions of the plotlabels in ListLinePlot and arranging them in GraphicsGrid?
Here I am trying to make different plots along with plotlabels. The next steps is to arrange the plots using graphics grids. Here is the code:
Needs["MaTeX`"]
nk = 50; GG = {0, 0}; XX = {\[Pi]/2,0}; YY = {0, \[Pi]/2}; MM = {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}; mag =1.30; padding = {{30, 5}, {30, 0}}; 
autoYTicks[range_] := Module[{ticks, positions, labels, threshold = 1*10^-10},positions = Subdivide[range[[1]], range[[2]], 4];
  labels = MaTeX[If[Abs[#] < threshold, "0.0", NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 1}]],    Magnification -> mag] & /@ positions;ticks = Transpose[{positions, labels}];
  ticks];
str = {MaTeX["\\Gamma", Magnification -> mag], MaTeX["X", Magnification -> mag], MaTeX["M", Magnification -> mag],MaTeX["\\Gamma", Magnification -> mag], MaTeX["Y", Magnification -> mag], MaTeX["M", Magnification -> mag]};
ham[x_, y_, hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] :=
   With[{t1 = ( {{0, 1},{1, 0}} ), t3 = ( {{1, 0},{0, -1}} ), t2 = ( {{0, -I},{I, 0}} ), t0 = ( {{I, 0},{0, I}} ), tx = {1, 0}, ty = {0, 1}},With[{qv = {x, y}, usR = hsR {1, 1, eS, eS eGxy, 1, 1, 1, eGxy}, usI = hsI {1, 1, -eS, -eS eGxy, 1, -1, 1, -eGxy},uspR = psR {1, 1, eS, eS eGxy, eP, eP, eP, eGxy eP}, uspI = psI {1, 1, eS, eS eGxy, eP, eP, eP, eGxy eP},   uhd = hd {1, 1}, upd = pd {1, 1}, n = 8}, Module[{mt}, mt = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
     Do[{mt[[i, j]] = a3  t3[[i, j]], mt[[i + 2, j + 2]] = a3  t3[[i, j]], mt[[i + 4, j + 4]] = a3  t3[[i, j]], mt[[i + 6, j + 6]] = a3  t3[[i, j]], mt[[i, j + 2]] = (usR[[1]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[1]]*t0[[i, j]] + uspR[[1]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[1]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, tx]],mt[[i + 2, j]] = (usR[[2]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[2]]*t0[[i, j]] +            uspR[[2]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[2]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, tx]], mt[[i + 6,j + 4]] = (usR[[3]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[3]]*t0[[i, j]] + uspR[[3]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[3]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, tx]],mt[[i + 4,j + 6]] = (usR[[4]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[4]]*t0[[i, j]] +           uspR[[4]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[4]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, tx]],mt[[i, j + 6]] = (usR[[5]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[5]]*t0[[i, j]] +uspR[[5]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[5]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, ty]],mt[[i + 2,j + 4]] = (usR[[6]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[6]]*t0[[i, j]] +           uspR[[6]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[6]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, ty]], 
       mt[[i + 6,j]] = (usR[[7]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[7]]*t0[[i, j]] + uspR[[7]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[7]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, ty]], 
       mt[[i + 4,j + 2]] = (usR[[8]]*t3[[i, j]] + usI[[8]]*t0[[i, j]] + 
           uspR[[8]]*t1[[i, j]] + uspI[[8]]*t2[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, ty]], 
       mt[[i, j + 4]] = (uhd[[1]]*t3[[i, j]] + upd[[1]]*t1[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, tx + ty]],mt[[i + 6,j + 2]] = (uhd[[2]]*t3[[i, j]] + upd[[2]]*t1[[i, j]]) Exp[I Dot[qv, -tx + ty]]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];mt + ConjugateTranspose[mt]]]];
EV[x_, y_, hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] := 
  Take[Sort[Eigenvalues[ham[x, y, hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, a3, eP, eS, eGxy]],Less],4];

f1[hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] := With[{p1 = GG, p2 = XX}, 
   With[{dx = (p2[[1]] - p1[[1]])/nk, dy = (p2[[2]] - p1[[2]])/nk}, 
    Table[Join[{i},EV[p1[[1]] + i*dx, p1[[2]] + i*dy, hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, 
       a3, eP, eS, eGxy]], {i, 0, nk}]]];
f2[hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] := 
  With[{p1 = XX, p2 = MM},With[{dx = (p2[[1]] - p1[[1]])/nk, dy = (p2[[2]] - p1[[2]])/nk}, 
    Table[Join[{i + nk}, EV[p1[[1]] + i*dx, p1[[2]] + i*dy, hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, 
       a3, eP, eS, eGxy]], {i, 1, nk}]]];
f3[hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] := With[{p1 = MM, p2 = GG}, 
   With[{dx = (p2[[1]] - p1[[1]])/nk, dy = (p2[[2]] - p1[[2]])/nk}, 
    Table[Join[{i + 2 nk},EV[p1[[1]] + i*dx, p1[[2]] + i*dy, hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, 
       a3, eP, eS, eGxy]], {i, 1, nk}]]];
fn[hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_] := Join[f1[hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, a3, eP, eS, eGxy], f2[hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, a3, eP, eS, eGxy],f3[hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, a3, eP, eS, eGxy]];
f[hsR_, hsI_, psR_, psI_, hd_, pd_, a3_, eP_, eS_, eGxy_, pLabel_] := With[{l = fn[hsR, hsI, psR, psI, hd, pd, a3, eP, eS, eGxy], xGrid = Range[0, 5 nk, nk]},   ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{l[[All, 1]], l[[All, 2]]}], Transpose[{l[[All, 1]], l[[All, 3]]}], 
     Transpose[{l[[All, 1]], l[[All, 4]]}],Transpose[{l[[All, 1]], l[[All, 5]]}]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,FrameLabel -> {"","\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(\[Mu]\)]\)"}, 
    FrameStyle ->Directive[Black, FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    GridLines -> {xGrid, None},GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Gray], Directive[Black, Dashed]},Frame -> True, Axes -> False,FrameTicks -> {{autoYTicks[{Min[l[[All, 2 ;; -1]]], Max[l[[All, 2 ;; -1]]]}], None}, {Table[{(i - 1) nk, Style[str[[i]], FontFamily -> "LaTeX"]}, {i, 1, 
         Length[str]}], None}}, FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 15]}, {Directive[Black,15]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3 nk}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/1.5,PlotLabel -> MaTeX[pLabel, Magnification -> mag], 
    ImagePadding -> padding, ImageMargins -> None]];
padding1 = {{30, 5}, {30, 0}};

GraphicsGrid[{{Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,    "\\text{Z}2000"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,"\\text{Z}2100"], ImagePadding -> padding1, 
    ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,"\\text{Z}2001"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,"\\text{Z}2101"], ImagePadding -> padding1, 
    ImageMargins -> None]}, {Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,"\\text{Z}3000"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1.0,1.0, -1.0, "\\text{Z}3100"], ImagePadding -> padding1, 
    ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., -0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 
     1.0, "\\text{Z}3001"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None],Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.0, -1.0,1.0, -1.0, "\\text{Z}3101"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None]}}, Spacings -> 0, ImageMargins -> None,AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {1000, 350}]

I obtained the following plot:

Notice that there is huge space in between the top frame border of each plot and corresponding plot labels. How to customize the space.
Again, if I plot with
GraphicsGrid[{{Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, "\\text{Z}2000"],    ImagePadding -> padding1, ImageMargins -> None], Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, "\\text{Z}2100"], ImagePadding -> padding1, ImageMargins -> None], 
   Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, "\\text{Z}2001"],ImagePadding -> padding1, ImageMargins -> None], Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 
     "\\text{Z}2101"], ImagePadding -> padding1, ImageMargins -> None]}, {, 
   Show[f[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,"\\text{Z}3100"], ImagePadding -> padding1, ImageMargins -> None], Show[f[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., -0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 
     "\\text{Z}3001"], ImagePadding -> padding1,ImageMargins -> None],}}, Spacings -> 0, ImageMargins -> None, AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {1000, 350}]

i.e.,removed the lower left and right plots, I get the following plot:

Here the plotlabels are just on top of the plots. I wonder both are basically same. But why the there are larger spaces when I include all th plots. How to resolve this?
Thank you in advance.
